# ICC and power for mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, statistical-power, intraclass-correlation

I'm simulating data for a mixed model in order to estimate the needed power for a study. I have 3 groups, a control group and two treatment groups. The effect sizes for the two treatment groups are 0.15 and 0.30 at the end of the study. The participants are measured at baseline, half way through the study and the end of the study.

My question is that when I simulate this data I see that the power to detect the effect of treatment increases as the ICC increases, something I didn't expect. I assumed that as the ICC increased, since the effective sample size decreases my power would decrease but I see the opposite result. Is this indicative of an error in my simulations or am I being too simplistic in my reasoning.

Here's a rough outline of the way I'm simulating the data.

1) I generate a random intercept for each subject. Each subject has 3 time points (T0,T1,T2).

2) For T1 I generate this based on their intercept + common effect for their treatment group (Control,Treat1,Treat2) + some random error N(0,0.5).

3) For T1 I generate this based on their intercept + 2 times the common effect for their treatment group since the effect is hypothesized to be linear (Control,Treat1,Treat2) + some random error N(0,0.5).